# Rails submitting a form through knockout.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, knockout.js

I've got a Rails 3.2 app which I've started to attach a lot of knockout.js bindings to. I would like to submit the form in JSON format to my Rails server.

I have a transaction form which has an amount

```
= form_for(@tran, :html => {"data-bind" => "submit: submitTrans"}) do |f|
    .field
        = f.label :date
        = f.date_select :date
    .field
        = f.label :voucher
        = f.number_field :voucher
    .field
        = f.label :amount
        = f.text_field :amount, "data-bind" => "value: amount, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', style: { background: amount() == 0 ? 'red' : 'white' }"
    .field
        = f.label :tax
        = f.text_field :tax, "data-bind" => "value: tax"
    .actions
        = f.submit 'Save'
```

Here is my knockout code:

```
#= require knockout

TranViewModel = ->
  # Observables
  self.amount = ko.observable("0")

  # Computed values
  self.tax = ko.computed(
    read: -> (self.amount() / 10).toFixed 2
    write: (value) -> value
    owner: this)


tranViewModel = new TranViewModel()

# Submit through AJAX
self.submitTrans = (formElement) ->
  alert ko.toJSON(tranViewModel)

# Apply keybindings on page load
$(document).ready (event) ->
  ko.applyBindings(tranViewModel)
```

When I'm using ko.toJSON like this I get 'undefined' returned in my alert box.

Do I have to create an instance of my model?
How do I get all my form attributes in JSON format and post these to my rails route '/transaction'?

The knockout documentation describes a pushJSON feature but the page doesn't exist anymore:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html

**Update #1**

I tried manually sending the json and this allowed me to create an object

```
self.submitTrans = (formElement) ->
  json = JSON.parse('{"tran": {"amount": "9999"}}')
  $.post("/trans", json, (returnedData) ->
    alert returnedData)
```

**Update #2**

I tried a number of things to get my form into JSON for submitting using $.post

```
self.submitTrans = (formElement) ->
  json = ko.toJSON(tranViewModel)
  $.post("/trans", json, (returnedData) ->
    alert returnedData)
```

This comes back as undefined. What do I pass to the ko.toJSON?

**Update #3**

I tried the example from the knockout website:

```
viewModel =
    firstName : ko.observable("Bert"),
    lastName : ko.observable("Smith"),
    pets : ko.observableArray(["Cat", "Dog", "Fish"]),
    type : "Customer"

self.submitTrans = (formElement) ->
  json = ko.toJSON(viewModel)
  $.post("/trans", json, (returnedData) ->
    alert returnedData)
```

This correctly formats the viewModel as JSON. This is because viewModel is an object not a function. If I however change my TranViewModel from a function to an object this breaks a lot of my bindings.  Which is the correct way of setting up my bindings? Should they be in an object or a function?

**Update #4**

My examples:
jsfiddle.net/p6Vcc/3 - When clicking submit the ko.toJSON does not collect all formElements, should I be adding observable to all my fields?

jsfiddle.net/p6Vcc/4 - Same example as the previous except recoded in coffeescript, now when clicking the submit it only shows the customers last name, and none of the other fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**
So looking at the coffee script provided above in the jsfiddle, there is an issue with the javascript being generated by the coffeescript:

```
  viewModel = __bind(function() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    return this.lastName = ko.observable("Smith");
  }, this);
```

Coffeescript always returns the last statement, so you have to add a @ at the end to "return this"

```
viewModel = =>
  @firstName = ko.observable("Bert")
  @lastName = ko.observable("Smith")
  @
```

resulting javascript

```
  viewModel = __bind(function() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("Smith");
    return this;
  }, this);
```

**Original Answer**

I'm not sure where you are having the trouble. I put your code above into a jsfiddle and it works as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/JasonMore/p6Vcc/2/

Can you update the fiddle to reflect the problem you are having?

**Javascript**

```
var viewModel = function() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
    this.lastName =ko.observable("Smith");
    this.pets = ko.observableArray(["Cat", "Dog", "Fish"]);
    this.type = "Customer";
};

var myViewModelInstance = new viewModel();

var jsonToPost = ko.toJSON(myViewModelInstance);

//alert(jsonToPost );

console.log(jsonToPost);
```

​

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/p6Vcc/3/  The problem is when you hit the 'submit' button in my example it is missing the email content. Do I have to add each field as a observable?

Comment: Also I'm using coffee script and have noticed that there is a problem when using knockout.js and coffeescript. Taking the same example and converting it to coffeescript http://jsfiddle.net/p6Vcc/4/ now we get "Smith" as the output instead of the expected JSON output.

Comment: I added an answer with the fixed coffeescript

Comment: I've changed the jsfiddle as per your improvements: http://jsfiddle.net/p6Vcc/8/ If I want that email field to be in the json is it correct practice to create a ko.observable on the item?

Comment: Yeah, in order for the data binding to work it should be an observable.